# ASP.NET MVC razor code and javascript errors

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have this code

```
@if (Model.Name!= null)
{
    <div>@Model.Name, <span>@Model.Email</span></div>
}
```

and I want to highlight the postal code if this condition - `IsFlaggedEmail` is true:

```
if (Model.IsFlaggedEmail(out flagComments))
{
        <span id="flagged" style="background-color:yellow;font-size:10pt">
}
```

and I want to display the comments in the title of the span (a tool tip). How can I write this in the cshtml file?

This is what I tried, but I keep getting errors like: "The if block is missing a closing "}" character. Make sure you have a matching "}" character for all the "{" characters within this block, and that none of the "}" characters are being interpreted as markup."

```
@if (Model.Name!= null)
{
    <div>@Model.Name,  @{
    string flagComments;
    if (Model.IsFlaggedEmail(out flagComments))
    {
        <span id="flagged" style="background-color:yellow;font-size:10pt">
    }
} @Model.Email</span></div>
}

@{ string comments;
    if (Model.IsFlaggedEmail(out comments)) {
        @section Scripts {

            $("#flagged").val('title', comments)

        }
 }}
```

Also, can I do something like that directly from jQuery?:

```
@if (Model.Name!= null)
{
    <div>@Model.Name, <span id="flagged">@Model.Email</span></div>
}


@{ string flagComments;
if (Model.IsFlaggedEmail(out flagComments)) { 
    @section Scripts {
        $('#flagged').css('background-collor', 'yellow')
        $('#flagged').attr('title', @flagComments);​
    }
}}
```

Comment: Try changing the syntax to: `@Model.Email</span> }</div>}`

Answer (score 0):

No javascript needed.
You can use something like:

`@if (Model.Name != null)
{
    string flagComments;
    bool isFlagged = Model.IsFlaggedEmail(out flagComments);
    <div>
        @Model.Name, <span id="@Html.Raw(isFlagged? "flagged": "")">@Model.Email</span>
</div>`

And for styling it is better to use CSS. (You have an ID `flagged`).
Also try to avoid spreading html building across `if` statements. It is always better to keep tags matching inside one clause.